# Passing e:MouseEvent as an argument via setInterval

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

So i have this function

```
capture_mc.buttonMode = true;
capture_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,captureImage);

function captureImage(e:MouseEvent):void { 
//lalalala

}
```

I want to call this function every 2 seconds (after mouse click event happens). 
I tried using setInterval

```
setInterval(captureImage,2000,e:MouseEvent);
```

but it leads to following error

```
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before colon.
```

What's wrong ?
And ya, i am new to AS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since this is AS3 you should be using [Timer](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Timer.html) and [TimerEvent](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/TimerEvent.html). I'll show you how in the example.

Now you'll need to separate your functions:

**edit:** I've updated this to be safer based on @(Juan Pablo Califano) suggestions. I would keep the same timer for ever if the amount of time isn't going to change.

```
// first param is milliseconds, second is repeat count (with 0 for infinite)
private var captureTimer:Timer = new Timer(2000, 0);
captureTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, handleInterval);

function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // call here if you want the first capture to happen immediately
    captureImage();

    // start it
    captureTimer.start();
}

function handleInterval(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    captureImage();
}

function captureImage():void
{
    // lalalala
}
```

You can also stop the timer with `captureTimer.stop()` whenever you want.

Comment: +1. It would also be a good idea to check whether your timer is running at the top of `handleClick`, and perhaps bailing out if it's running (or reseting the timer if that makes sense given the context). This could be implemented with a simple boolean flag or checking if `captureTimer` is not null. Otherwise, you could end up with multiple timers running and you won't have a way to stop them (because you'd be losing the reference to the old ones when you assign a new `Timer` object to the `captureTimer` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you should use the `parameterName:ParameterType` syntax only when declaring formal parameters (or when declaring `var`s and `const`s). Meaning, this is valid only when you are defining a function:

```
function func(paramName:Type){
}
```

When you call the function, you don't have to put the type of the arguments.

So, your function call should look like this:

```
setInterval(captureImage,2000,e);
```